# Can I skip first segment of multi-airline ticket?

Tags: airlines, bookings, travel-agents

I want to book a ticket through an online travel agent which combines two airlines. The flight itinerary is A-B-C and C-B. Segment A-B is operated by airline company A1 and segment B-C-B operated by airline company A2.

Can I skip A-B segment of this itinerary and just board in B?

Comment: I would like to point out that the duplicate question is for the same airline. Here the booking is for multi-airline.

Answer (score 1):

Usually if you do not use the first part (A-B) of a combined ticket, you are being counted as "no show" and your further reservation (B-C) would be subject to be freed for other travellers.

This can be different if no agreement between airlines exist (and the combination was only provided by your travel agent). In this case I would suggest to ask the second airline or your travel agent directly.